# Storing a UUlD as a VARCHAR in Postgresql WITHOUT any formatting

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, uuid

I am moving data between two tables.

The first column is a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER in a SQL Server database.
The second column is a VARCHAR in a Postgresql database.

After the transfer:

```
The SQL Server UNIQUEIDENTIFIER value:  27E66FD9-79B8-4342-92A9-3CA87E497E69
The Postgresql VARCHAR value:           b'27E66FD9-79B8-4342-92A9-3CA87E497E69'
```

I need the Postgresql VARCHAR to store the exact value, without the extra formatting (b'....')

I am using DBeaver to edit the database. What can I do while keeping the column a VARCHAR (needed for the underlying code) ?

Comment: VARCHAR is the wrong choice, `uuid` will indeed store it without any formatting. But `b'....'` is not how a varchar is stored in Postgres. You transfer tool probably added that prefix and the single quotes. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5b869b615584be44a380b55313d3fee8

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name is correct! You want the column defined as [UUID](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-uuid.html), and it is your translation tool appending  the binary indicator and doing so incorrectly. If you try it Postgres (via DBeaver) throws exception "invalid binary". Postgres supports several formats for UUIDs including the SQL Server value you posted. What you see when selecting a uuid is the Standard Form, and is always generated output format. To get a varchar representation cast to text and use the replace function to remove the dashes. See fiddle link below.

Comment: In a minor since uuid is similar to dates, what you see is *strictly for display and conversion only*. But unlike dates Postgres 
detects the various formats automatically. See [fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6d7e85a9123ed67b0fae31c0f39b1505). It creates several rows using differing uuid formats then 
selects each using a different format.  It also demonstrates removing the dashes (-) from the Standard Form.